# How to make a report based on how much interactions (with contacts/opportunities/leads etc) each used had?

Tags: reporting, custom-reports

Basically, we are quite new in salesforce and we need to adjust our reporting. Could you please advise how do I check how many interactions (with opportunities, leads contacts etc) our users had in let's say last 30 days? Plenty of other CRMs offer such metric as interaction, but I cant find it in salesforce.

Thank you,
Erw

Comment: You can use a report of activities with Leads/ Contacts, etc. That will give you how many activities (emails, calls, etc) were logged in each record.

Comment: Thank you, I am happy it is possible. Could you please give me a small clue how do I do that in reports section?

Comment: If you are new to Salesforce, the Trailhead site is a good resource for tutorials such as these [on reports](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/search?keywords=reports).